# Android Studio messes up brazilian-portuguese characters

Tags: android, configuration, idioms

My project isn't showing any portuguese characters. When I try to type a word like "Não" it returns NÃ£o".

The funny thing is that when I get the string from res/string.xml, it shows the word correctly.

Any idea why?

Things I've tried so far and did not work out:

1. File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Encondings, I've changed everything to UTF-8 and others, rebuild/cleaned the project, and it kept the same.

EDIT:

I can upload a video on youtube showing it, if it helps with the solution!

There goes an image of what is happening:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My file build.gradle had this line:

```
compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
```

Because of that I wasn't able to change anything. Now it's fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is really hard to explain why is it is, I had same with russian characters, but only on SOME devices. I've just checked to do same as you on `Genymotion` and it displays correctly... From my investigation it is up to each device how to display given characters, but also I assume it could happen because `Android` knows how to works with `Resources`, but doesn't with `String`s from code. When you create folders for different languages you don't say that default must be `English`. So system gonna detect and display. I'm not sure 100%, but this is what I understood from [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Anyways, for using `String` object in `TextView` from code and displaying foreign (from English) languages we have just 2 options:

*1) Add .ttf file for particular text/Unicode
2) html format*

**Example for first option:**

```
String s="(Mouy t'ngai) (១ ថ្ងៃ)";
TextView text_view1 = null;
text_view1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
Typeface font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "khmerOS.ttf");
text_view1.setTypeface(font);
text_view1.setText(s);

// you can use different type of .ttf like
TAU_BHON.TTF
molten.ttf
arialuni.ttf
```

**Example of Second option:**

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("\\u27A1");
```

[Source](http://suniljp.blogspot.in/2015/02/different-language-textunicode-display.html).

P.S. If I missed something, please fill free to notice that.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion but it sounds like too much of a trouble for me. :( I'm wondering why File Enconding -> UTF-8 won't work.